# Using XAML only to prevent characters from being entered in a TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I know how to accomplish this with some code behind my XAML but I am wondering if it is possible to restrict what characters are entered in a textbox using pure XAML with no C#?

I have tried to research this but have found nothing, So I am assuming its not possible so just checking here.

Answer (score 1):

Could write a [markup extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815(v=vs.110).aspx) returning a filter in the text change event. It's fairly messy and still requires the code for the extension, but you could then provide the limited characters in XAML.

Alternatively an [attached property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.100).aspx) could provide the same functionality and is probably a bit cleaner in this case.

Lastly you could subclass the `TextBox` control and make the logic and internal part of the control that can be configured with a dependency property.

Comment: That prevents all characters. I want to specify that certain characters are not allowed.

Comment: @CathalMF: I noticed.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit the textbox "`Behavior<TextBox>`" and add your logic in OnPreviewTextInput event to check for validation.